# Null Pointer while generating sphere

Tags: android, opengl-es, nullpointerexception

Im trying to create a sphere in opengl es 2.0 but I getting a null pointer exception. I've been stuck on this for hours. After checking the logcat it seems to find a couple of vertices but then the index buffer always hits null pointer straight after.

```
 private void generateSphereCoords(float radius, int stacks, int slices) {
    for (int stackNumber = 0; stackNumber <= stacks; stackNumber++) {
        for (int sliceNumber = 0; sliceNumber <= slices; sliceNumber++) {
            float theta = (float) (stackNumber * Math.PI / stacks);
            float phi = (float) (sliceNumber * 2 * Math.PI / slices);
            Log.i("theta", String.valueOf(theta));
            Log.i("phi", String.valueOf(phi));
            float sinTheta = FloatMath.sin(theta);
            float sinPhi = FloatMath.sin(phi);
            float cosTheta = FloatMath.cos(theta);
            float cosPhi = FloatMath.cos(phi);
            vertices = new float[]{radius * cosPhi * cosTheta, radius * sinPhi * cosTheta, radius * sinTheta};
            Log.i("vertexX", String.valueOf(vertices[0]));
            Log.i("vertexY", String.valueOf(vertices[1]));
            Log.i("vertexZ", String.valueOf(vertices[2]));
            // a float is 4 bytes, therefore I multiply the number of vertices by 4.
            ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);// (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());// use the device hardware's native byte order
            vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();// create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
            vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
            vertexBuffer.position(0);// set the buffer to read the first coordinate
        }
    }

    for (int stackNumber = 0; stackNumber <= stacks; stackNumber++) {
        for (int sliceNumber = 0; sliceNumber <= slices; sliceNumber++) {
            ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexCount * 2);// (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());// use the device hardware's native byte order
            indexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();// create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
            indexBuffer.put((short) ((stackNumber * slices) + (sliceNumber % slices)));
            indexBuffer.put((short) (((stackNumber + 1) * slices) + (sliceNumber % slices)));
            indexBuffer.position(0);// set the buffer to read the first coordinate
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your vertex buffer and index buffer outside of your loops. As it is you are recreating the vertex buffer for each vertex and the index buffer for each pair of indices.

```
private static final int VERTICES_PER_COORD = 3;
private void generateSphereCoords(float radius, int stacks, int slices) {

    // Create vertex buffer here:
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((stacks + 1) * (slices + 1) * VERTICES_PER_COORD * 4);// (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());// use the device hardware's native byte order
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();// create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer

    for (int stackNumber = 0; stackNumber <= stacks; stackNumber++) {
        for (int sliceNumber = 0; sliceNumber <= slices; sliceNumber++) {
            float theta = (float) (stackNumber * Math.PI / stacks);
            float phi = (float) (sliceNumber * 2 * Math.PI / slices);
            Log.i("theta", String.valueOf(theta));
            Log.i("phi", String.valueOf(phi));
            float sinTheta = FloatMath.sin(theta);
            float sinPhi = FloatMath.sin(phi);
            float cosTheta = FloatMath.cos(theta);
            float cosPhi = FloatMath.cos(phi);
            vertices = new float[]{radius * cosPhi * cosTheta, radius * sinPhi * cosTheta, radius * sinTheta};
            Log.i("vertexX", String.valueOf(vertices[0]));
            Log.i("vertexY", String.valueOf(vertices[1]));
            Log.i("vertexZ", String.valueOf(vertices[2]));
            // a float is 4 bytes, therefore I multiply the number of vertices by 4.

            // add this vertex tp the buffer:        
            vertexBuffer.put(vertices);                
        }
    }
    vertexBuffer.position(0);// set the buffer to read the first coordinate

    // Create index buffer here:
    ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((stacks + 1) * (slices + 1) * 2 * 2);// (number of index values * 2 bytes per short)
    ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());// use the device hardware's native byte order
    indexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();// create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer

    for (int stackNumber = 0; stackNumber <= stacks; stackNumber++) {
        for (int sliceNumber = 0; sliceNumber <= slices; sliceNumber++) {                
            indexBuffer.put((short) ((stackNumber * slices) + (sliceNumber % slices)));
            indexBuffer.put((short) (((stackNumber + 1) * slices) + (sliceNumber % slices)));                
        }
    }
    indexBuffer.position(0);// set the buffer to read the first index
}
```